# Prove or disprove: there is a surjective homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Prove or disprove: there is a surjective homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

*Attempt*. I believe there is no such function. Of course 
$\phi(1)=1$, but if $\phi(x)=k_0$ then i can not see how do I get a contradiction from here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Hint:* If there is such a surjection, then kernel of $\phi$ is a non-zero prime ideal (*why?*) and now use $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID.

Comment: Another hint: what would be $\phi(1/n)$? Keeping in mind that $\phi(nq)=n\phi(q)$ for any homomorphism $\phi$ (of additive groups even!), $q\in\Bbb{Q}$ and $n\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, i see. For example, we would get $1=\phi(1)=2\phi(1/2)$, a contradiction (the same argument would be given for the fact that there is no surjective homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Correct, Nikolaos. And, yes the same argument kills the possibility of a surjective homomorphism from $\Bbb{Q}$ to $\Bbb{Z}$. BTW, is the question about homomorphisms of **rings** in particular? Your choice of tags suggests that as does the beginning $\phi(1)=1$. But the same argument even kills the existence of surjective homomorphism of groups: if $\phi(1)=m\neq0$ then what is $\phi(1/m^2)$?

Comment: $\phi(f) = f(0)$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This kills the possibility of *any* ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So it does @egreg (the OP did figure it out, so IMO it would have been nice to let them post an answer rather than jumping the gun) Another common argument for that would be the following (suggested also by Krish): The kernel is an ideal. But fields (such as $\Bbb{Q}$) only have the trivial ones, so a ring homomorphism from a field is always injective...

Comment: Nikolaos, you can still post an answer of your own. That way you get feedback on your understanding/exposition of the details.

Comment: Of course, thank you Jyrki!

Answer (score 3):

There is *no* ring homomorphism* $\alpha\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$.

Indeed, as an additive group, $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible, so the image of $\alpha$ is divisible as well and the only divisible subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\{0\}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, we're done.

From another point of view, if $F$ is a field and $f\colon F[x]\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring homomorphism, then $f(F)$ is a subfield** of $\mathbb{Z}$, so…

<sub>* Other than the zero map, if you don't require $\alpha(1)=1$.</sub>
<sub>** Or the zero subring, if you don't assume rings to be unital.</sub>